# Drawing polygons in canvas with the mouse: coord issue when the div is included in the design of the site

Tags: javascript, canvas, coordinates

I'm working with this script ["Drawing polygons with the mouse"](http://www.javascriptfr.com/codes/DESSINER-POLYGONES-AVEC-SOURIS_51910.aspx) and it works very well.
The issue I have is when I put the canvas in the design of my site. The canvas is thus now in relative position and the coords are wrong. I have a lag between my cursor and the draw…

If I set the div in position: fixed, there is no problem.

The positions are declared as follows:

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop;
```

How to fix this? How to put the canvas in my design and have the right coords?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try my "simple" mouse code (simple because it does not take into account border/padding/HTML offset):

```
function getMouse(e, canvas) {
  var element = canvas, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0, mx, my;

  // Compute the total offset
  if (element.offsetParent !== undefined) {
    do {
      offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
      offsetY += element.offsetTop;
    } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
  }

  // This isn't the best code because I am not adding padding and border style widths to offset. I'm just keeping it simple.

  mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
  my = e.pageY - offsetY;

  return {x: mx, y: my};
}
```